# $\int_0^\pi g(\theta)\sin(\theta)\cos^n(\theta)\equiv 0$ imply $g(\theta)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $g\in C^{\infty}_c([0,\pi])$,$\int_0^\pi g(\theta)sin(\theta)\cos^n(\theta)d\theta\equiv 0$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$, does that imply that $$g(\theta)\equiv 0$$

Comment: The integral of $\cos^{n}x \sin x$ is zero on the interval $[0,\pi]$ for odd $n$. So, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is negative. $g$ can have countably many removable discontinuities.

**Faulty answer** unless $\int_0^\pi g(\theta) \, \text{d}\theta = 0$

For the modified question, suppose $g$ is an even function or otherwise we just replace $g$ by its even extension on $[0, \pi]$.

Since $\cos(n\theta)$ can be written as a polynomial of $\cos(\theta)$, we have the Fourier cosine series of $g$ is zero. Hence $g = 0$.

Comment: Edited. Please relook it

Comment: it is $(cos(\theta))^n$

Comment: I have mentioned that $\cos(n\theta)$ can be written as a polynomial of $\cos(\theta)$ and the integral is linear so from the assumption the Fourier coefficients are $0$.

Comment: can u write more explicitly, I don't understand

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Only the Fourier coefficients with odd index are zero. NTL my thought is, say $n = 3$, $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$. But for, say $n = 2$,  $\cos(2\theta)$ has a non-zero constant term in the polynomial expansion of $\cos(\theta)$ and the Fourier coefficient for $n = 2$ is non-zero.

Comment: sorry for modification again